# Is there a way to sum the extracted positions from a matrix using sum() function in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

```
Matrix =[1 2 3 4 5 6; 6 5 4 3 2 1];

[f0,c0]=find(M<4); 
[f1,c1]=find(M>4);
```

Hi I extracted the positions given these condtions using find function(),but I don't seem to find a way to add up those respective positons using sum() function in Matlab any ideas!?

Comment: What will be the output for the given matrix? How did you use the sum function?

Comment: Hi the output of the sum of values in [f0,c0] should be 12 (1,2,3 located in file 1 + 321 located in file 2),same with the other condition(5+6 located in file 1 +6+5 located in file 2)

Comment: Result=sum(Matrix(f0,c0)) but result is not correct

Comment: %3) Use the next matrix
M=[1 2 3 4 5 6; 6 5 4 3 2 1];
s=size(M);
largo_fila=size(M,1);
largo_columna=size(M,2);
s1=0;
s2=0;
for i=1:1:largo_fila
    for a=1:1:largo_columna
     
        if M(i,a)<4
          s1=s1+M(i,a);
        elseif M(i,a)>=4
            s2=s2+M(i,a);
        end
    end
end

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the details

Comment: `find` is usually not needed. `M(M<4)` is all the elements of `M` that are smaller than 4. You can directly `sum()` them.

Answer (score 0):

Like Cris Luengo wrote, just use:

```
M=[1 2 3 4 5 6; 6 5 4 3 2 1];
sum(M(M<4)) % ans = 12
sum(M(M>4)) % ans = 22
```